# The ring of global sections of a regular scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, regular-rings

Let $X$ be a Noetherian regular scheme. Is $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ a regular ring? For affine schemes this is true, see [02IU on the Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02IU).

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users

Answer (score 14):

The answer is no. For instance, take the quadratic cone
$$
Y = \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2))
$$
and let $X$ be its blowup at the vertex. Then $X$ is regular, but
$$
H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X) = H^0(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y) = \Bbbk[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2)
$$
is not.